# Xpath find a html element by class name and cellpadding

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, html-parsing

How can I find a `tbody` element with `class="centered"` and `cellpadding="4"`? I have tried the following: `"//tbody[contains(@class='bordercolor' and @cellpadding='4')]"`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `contains()` function works on a single value and it takes two parameters. The first is the value to test and the second is the value to look for.

So, you need to adjust your predicate to apply `contains()` for each of the attributes that you are testing, and provide the value as a second param instead of asserting an `=` expression:

```
//tbody[contains(@class, 'bordercolor') and contains(@cellpadding, '4')]
```

If you wanted to test whether the values are equal, not just contain those values, then remove `contains()` completely:

```
//tbody[@class='bordercolor' and @cellpadding='4']
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it's apparently also invalid. `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//tbody[contains(@class='bordercolor') and contains(@cellpadding='4')]" is invalid: [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x8060000d (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js :: element.findByXPath :: line 356"  data: no]`. I'm using selenium for python.

Comment: whoops, also didn't notice you were using `=` instead of providing the value as the second param. I have updated the answer.